# How to write Django ORM query for .... WHERE substring(field1, 1, 2) in ('AB', 'BC')?

Tags: django

How to write Django ORM filter for following query.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1 WHERE substring(field1, 1, 2) in ('AB', 'BC')
```

I want to write query using

```
Model1.objects.filter(.....)
```

I think sql query self explaining, I don't have to give more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily with the django ORM combining `only`, `filter` and `Q` [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```py
from django.db.models import Q

Model1.objects.only('field1', 'field2', 'field3').filter(Q(field1__startswith='AB') | Q(field1__startswith='BC'))
```

Comment: This is good answer. What do you think if I have long list of strings? Will there any performance issue?

Comment: Install https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ in your developer environment and you'll be able to see the generated query in a couple of clicks,  and how long it took. It also does lots of other  useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks I know that... I am  building graphql query, Debug Toolbar does not give much info... Instead, I am using Kolo. But yea, you gave idea for benchmarking. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you cannot use raw SQL queries using the raw() function?

Something like:

```
Model1.objects.raw('SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1 WHERE substring(field1, 1, 2) in ('AB', 'BC')')
```

Documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Thanks R. Uziel, I know it can be done with raw query. I was thinking whether it can be done with ORM (I mentioned ORM way in question).